# Read multiple json files in different folders in separate spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a directory called `data`. Within this directory there are four subdirectories: `01`, `02`, `03` and `04`. Within these directories are hundres of JSON files that I want to load into a spark dataframe per subdirectory. What is the best way to do this?

I've tried this so far:

```
directories = ['01', '02', '03', '04']
for files in directories:
    filepath = '/home/jovyan/data/{}/*.json.gz'
    df = spark.read.format('json').option("header", "true").schema(schema).load(filepath)
    # exectute rest code here
```

Comment: try loading `'/home/jovyan/data/{01,02,03,04}/*.json.gz`. no need to use for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.walk()` to find all files and directories in your `data` folder recursively. For example, if in the future, you add a new folder `07`, you don't have to change your current code.

```py
import os

path = './data/'
for root, directories, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
        if filepath.endswith('.json') or filepath.endswith('.json.gz'):
            df = spark.read.format('json').option("header", "true").schema(schema).load(filepath)
            # exectute rest code here
```